# Can Gutenberg be used as an editor on a page?

Tags: block-editor

I have a few dozen WordPress sites using the Classic Editor. When an Editor/Author/User logs in, they cannot access "wp-admin".  All "admin" functions use custom pages on the front end of the site.

One of the pages lets users create/edit posts and uses the Classic Editor. Works just like the classic editor on the back end.

However, I'd like to transition users over to Gutenberg and I can't find any code examples for implementing Gutenberg on the front end of the site as an editor. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

As Tammy [states here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/show-gutenberg-editor-on-frontend/):

> There is a plugin you may want to dig a little into
>   https://github.com/tomjn/Frontenberg, this is purely a demonstration
>   of putting Gutenberg on the front, not something that is planned yet.
>   It may hold some insights though for you. Right now there is no
>   option/shortcode to do this.

That was written a year and a half ago, so many things have changed. It may be simpler now.